# Stack discipline assembly

Tags: assembly, stack

So I'm studying for a systems midterm, and an old midterm of a similar course had this problem , with C and assembly code as follows:

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(!b)
    {
        return a;
    }
    return gcd(b, a%b);
}

0x08048394 <+0>: push %ebp
0x08048395 <+1>: mov %esp,%ebp
0x08048397 <+3>: sub $0x10,%esp
0x0804839a <+6>: mov 0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x0804839d <+9>: mov 0xc(%ebp),%ecx
0x080483a0 <+12>: test %ecx,%ecx
0x080483a2 <+14>: je 0x80483b7 <gcd+35>
0x080483a4 <+16>: mov %eax,%edx
0x080483a6 <+18>: sar $0x1f,%edx
0x080483a9 <+21>: idiv %ecx
0x080483ab <+23>: mov %edx,0x4(%esp)
0x080483af <+27>: mov %ecx,(%esp)
0x080483b2 <+30>: call 0x8048394 <gcd>
0x080483b7 <+35>: leave
0x080483b8 <+36>: ret
```

They give us that the starting value of %esp is 0xffff1000, and tell us that gcd(213, 18) will result in: gcd(213, 18), gcd(18, 15), gcd(15, 3), and gcd(3, 0).  They then ask what the value of %esp is before the execution of the return instruction for gcd(15, 3).

The solution says that it is 0xffff0fcc.  I don't quite understand why.  Here is my reasoning:

We subtracted 0x10 three times, and we called gcd(18, 15) and gcd(15, 3), which combined we should subtract 0x30 and 0x8 from the stack.  So shouldn't we be at 0xffff0fc8?  Then, after we return we add 0x4 again so that $esp is 0xffff0fcc, but not before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they mean that `esp` = 0xffff1000 right before this line:

```
0x08048394 <+0>: push %ebp
```

then you subtract from `esp`:

```
4: 0x08048394 <+0>: push %ebp
16: 0x08048397 <+3>: sub $0x10,%esp
4: 0x080483b2 <+30>: call 0x8048394 <gcd>; gcd(18, 15)
```

and then:

```
4: 0x08048394 <+0>: push %ebp
16: 0x08048397 <+3>: sub $0x10,%esp
4: 0x080483b2 <+30>: call 0x8048394 <gcd>; gcd(15, 3)
```

and then:

```
0: because "leave" undoes "sub $0x10,%esp" and "push %ebp"
```

with that you get 0xffff1000 - 2 * (4 + 16 + 4) = 0xffff0fd0.

If, OTOH, `esp` = 0xffff1000 before `call 0x8048394 <gcd>; gcd(213, 18)` in the main program, then the above value reduces by the size of the return address, 4, and you get 0xffff0fcc.

I'd say that the problem statement (assuming you haven't altered its meaning) is a bit ambiguous. I, too, would count in the size of the parameters even for the call `gcd(213, 18)` in the main program. But then there's another question. Is there any stack alignment performed by the main program before `gcd(213, 18)` and should I count it as well? Note that inside of `gcd()` there's stack alignment as the function uses only 8 bytes to pass parameters recursively, but allocates 16.

To correctly solve this problem (=to get the number expected by the teacher), it must unambiguously state exactly at what point in the code `esp` = 0xffff1000 and make sure that that code is included.

Comment: Yeah, I worded it wrong and also didn't read it clearly.  The exact wording was "Also imagine that prior to the invocation, the value of %esp is 0xffff1000, that is, 0xffff1000 is the value of %esp immediately before the execution of the call instruction."  So basically, I was completely wrong.  So we're subtracting 24 for gcd(213, 18), then subtracting 24 again for gcd(18, 15).  However, I don't understand why it reduces by 4 if we haven't executed leave or return yet?  Fwiw it's problem 5, part b here http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15213-f11/www/oldexams/exam1-f11.pdf.

Comment: `call` pushes the return address on the stack. `ret` removes it from there.

Comment: And then you say `They then ask what the value of %esp is before the execution of the return instruction for gcd(15, 3).`, so `leave` should've already executed if you're at `ret`.

Comment: Right, thank you.  I think I need to start reading both the instructions and the assembly code more carefully.